# How to attach new vocal in any video without removing old vocals using ffmpeg libraby

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to create a video that have new vocals but old background music. Is it possible using ffmpeg library?

I do not have very much idea about how to do it but I assume that any video contains two layers of audio.

- Background music and
- Vocals or dialogues

I want to remove original vocals of video and add new vocals but I do not want to disturb the original background music of video.

Is there anyone who can help me for it. I am using ffmpeg library for it.

Comment: Does the original file have one audio stream with both vocals and music, or two audio streams with separate vocals and music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I have done this in the past is as follows:

- extract audio from video using ffmpeg
- merge extracted audio with the new video you want to add using sox (http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)
- add the merged audio track back into the video using ffmpeg

This is likely not the most efficient way to do this, but it did work reliably.